# Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object -

Tags: php, joomla, mysqli

I'm trying to execute a query but keep getting an error Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object. I have searched through forums for answers but i'm very new to php and a lot of the stuff I found is very advanced for me to get my head around. I'm working with Joomla, the connection to the database is working and I can successfully write to the table I am working with but can't select the information from it without getting this error.

```
<?php                       
                    $message = '';
                    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
                    if($db->connect_error)
                    {
                        //if error assign to message
                        $message = $db->connect_error;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM jos_offer';
                        $result = $db->query($sql);
                        if($db->error)
                        {
                            $message = $db->error;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
                            {
                                echo '<div>'.$row['student_id'].$row['offer'].'</div>'; 
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ?>
```

Comment: Does this query: `SELECT * FROM jos_offer` work when you run it in phpMyAdmin or whatever?

Comment: Yes the query works in phpMyAdmin

Comment: There is not enough information here. Please present a [testcase](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Are you on 1.5 or the current code base 2.5/3? Also is this in the CMS or a stand alone application?

Comment: Why are you not just using the Joomla api for this? Also always use #__  not the hard coded prefix. Joomla also has a lot of error handling built in, you don't need to worry about the connection unless you are connecting to a database that is not your cms database, if the connection is dead you'll know way before this point..

Answer (score 1):

If you are in Joomla you should take advantage of the APIS to make your code cleaner and simpler.

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = $db->getQuery(true)
      ->select('*')->from($db->quoteName('#__offer'));
$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
//$results = $db->loadAssocList(); // If you really want that, not sure why you would.
 if ($db->getErrorNum())
{
 echo JText::sprintf('JLIB_DATABASE_ERROR_FUNCTION_FAILED', 
            $db->getErrorNum(), $db->getErrorMsg()) . '<br />';

   return;
}

if (!empty($results))
(      
  foreach ($results as $result)
  {
     echo '<div>'.$result->student_id. ' ' ,  $result->offer . '</div>'; 
    // Or switch to the associative array version
    // echo '<div>'.$result['student_id']. ' ' . $result['offer'] . '</div>'; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())</s>

Should be:

```
while($row = $db->loadResultArray($result))
```

`$result` is not the object you think it is. It's a `MySQLi_resultset_resource` which you can't do very much with other than pass it to `fetch_assoc`

Unless you have documentation for the Joomla database wrapper I would suggest not to use it. The native PHP wrappers are at least just as good if not better.

Look at the MySQLi wrapper: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: What? No. You fetch from the result. `query` gives you a resultset resource. Assuming this is mysqli.

Comment: Nope. This is how the _old_ database wrapper functions used to work http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: Since it _seems_ like the DB object has all the fetch functions (called `load` apparently) I still think I'm correct. http://docs.joomla.org/API15:JDatabase I think `loadResultArray` is the function most similar to `fetch_assoc`?

Comment: No, it isn't. Those function on the result of a query, too. Not the DB resource. Read the page you linked, carefully.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. That function list is of the `JDatabase` class. I can't find any mention of a result-set class.

Comment: I'm referring to your mysqli link.

Comment: In that case I am really confused. The old API didn't even have objects! :D

Comment: Changing $result to $db has fixed the error but its not echoing any results

Comment: @Frits: Then why do you link to `mysqli`, which introduced them?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't understand what you mean. MySQLi didn't introduce a new API. The OO API for MySQLi was added in PHP5. Source: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php The _old_ API - what I assume the JDatabase is modeled after didn't have objects. This is still in response to your statement that "I am making things up". I'm am not making things up, I am making an educated guess.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen: You seem to be confused. Mysqli is not "the old API", and it mostly certainly does "have objects". None of this explains why you think it's possible or even sensical to obtain rows from a DB resource, rather than a resultset resource (which is obtained from a _query_ operation). What do you think `$db->fetch_assoc` could ever possibly mean, unless the API you were using were _horribly_ broken?

Comment: @Frits: Yep, you're right: it was different in `mysqli_query`. The OO variant `mysqli->query` is object-oriented. However, these functions are part of the same library and, in _both_ cases, rows come from the resultset (here, `$result`), and not the original DB connection resource (here, `$db`). That's all I mean. All that being said, I don't know `JFactory` either (hence I didn't post an answer!)...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help I got it to work using

```
$db->setQuery($query);
if( $rows = $db->loadObjectList() )
```